# Requesting Android permissions in Qt 6

Tags: qt6, qtandroidextras

I am trying to convert a Qt 5 app to Qt 6.
In Qt 5 we can request Android permissions as follows:

```
QStringList permissions;
//...
QtAndroid::PermissionResultMap resultHash = QtAndroid::requestPermissionsSync(permissions);
for (const auto &perm : permissions)
{
    if(resultHash[perm] == QtAndroid::PermissionResult::Denied)
    {
        qDebug() << "Permission denied:" << perm;
        return false;
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent in Qt 6? Or is the only way to manually implement this using JNI?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the new Qt6 permission API (which is still under development, however can be used): [QtAndroidPrivate Namespace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtandroidprivate.html)

Example:

```
#include <QtCore/private/qandroidextras_p.h>

bool checkPermission()
{
    auto r = QtAndroidPrivate::checkPermission(QtAndroidPrivate::Storage).result();
    if (r == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied)
    {
        r = QtAndroidPrivate::requestPermission(QtAndroidPrivate::Storage).result();
        if (r == QtAndroidPrivate::Denied)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've edited the relevant parts of your comment into your answer.  I think that's enough to no longer qualify as "link only"

Answer (score 1):

There is no permission handling API in `Qt6` yet. However, it is under making. You can follow the situation from [QTBUG-90498](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90498). It looks like it is scheduled for `Qt6.4` release which I assume will be due some time in the fall 2022. You can find a code review link from the bug report which might help you in writing your own implementation.

I would recommend you to take a look into [QNativeInterface::QAndroidApplication::runOnAndroidMainThread](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qnativeinterface-qandroidapplication.html#runOnAndroidMainThread) which you can use for asynchronous calling on the Android UI thread.