# QtAndroid: no such file or directory

Tags: android, qt

I'have installed QtCreator and followed that guide: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-getting-started.html

It seems to me, I configured tools for developing android properly. Furthermore, I have already tested some apps deployed on my android device.

For some reasons #include  in QtCreator gave me an arror QtAndroid: no such file or directory.

Reinstalled all tools twice. What should I do to solve this problem?

Reinstalled all tools twice. (guide https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-getting-started.html)

Comment: Why do you need this include?

Comment: In some guides I've seen that it has functionality to give some android permissions for my app. I'am only studying, so, maybe there is another way to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71216717/requesting-android-permissions-in-qt-6

Comment: Thanx, Alexander! I will try!